# php code is Running before calling the function. (on loading the page whole php code get launched)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, web

Here is my code.. PHP code is running before button click

```
$(document).click(function(){
    $('input[type="button"]').click(function(){
        <?php 
        include "posts/connections/db_connect.php";
        mysql_query("insert into post_tags(post_id,user_id) values(3,2)");
        ?>
    });
});

</script>
<input type="button" value="submit" />
```

and the HTML element is

Comment: well yes php is run server side, so whats the question?

Comment: Are you trying to submit the form without the page refreshing? if so you need to use ajax to send the data to the php file and its there that you will need to put your  php query and include your database connection?

Comment: PHP can't be executed inside javascript. Because javascript runs on browser and PHP run on server. If you want you can go for an ajax call.

Comment: do u want 
<?php 
        include "posts/connections/db_connect.php";
        mysql_query("insert into post_tags(post_id,user_id) values(3,2)");
        ?> to execute after button click

Comment: Yes. i want to execute the query after button click.